# Match certain text, but omit it in the output

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++'s find and replace regex feature, is there any way to match certain text, but not include it in the replacement? For instance: `([ab][cd] )*` for matching a strings such as `ac ad bc bc ad`, and replacing it with `$0`, except not including the `[ab]` part, or in the case of the string above, `c d c c d`. While only answers for Notepad++'s regex dialect will be useful, if anyone knows a solution in some other dialect, I'd be curious to see them, and they might apply to this dialect anyway.

**EDIT:**

The pattern is easy to match, the part I don't know how to do is get the replacement to do what I want. For the example expression I gave, the pattern `(?:[ab]([cd]))*` actually works, with `$1` in the replace box, but that said, it doesn't work for my actual use case because the `[ab][cd]` is a sub-expression of the result (note that I didn't think that it would make a difference, else I would have posted this in the original question, my apologies); a better example would be where I want strings like `f(ac ad bc bc ad):` replaced with `f(ac ad bc bc ad): f'(c d c c d)` (so, really I want a regular addition). I tried using the regex `([a-z])\((?:[ab]([cd] ?))*\):`, with the replacement being `$0$1'($2)`, but that results in the value of `$2` being whatever it last matched (i.e., `f(ac ad bc bc ad): f'(d)`).

Comment: What is the expected output for `ac ad bc bc ad`?

Comment: What is wrong with searching for `[ab]([cd])` and replacing with `$1`?

Comment: Or [`[ab](?=[cd])`](https://regex101.com/r/RGebqN/2) replacing with an empty string?

Comment: Because I need the whole `[ab][cd]` pattern repeated indefinitely, and I can't use `$n` with an indefinitely high number (as far as I know).

Comment: If you do a *Replace All* with notepad++ there would be no problem.

Comment: This is usually a case for `awk` not notepad++.

Comment: I interacted with OP by comments. Both before and after update if you see. @l'L'l

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ find and replace functionality doesn't provide a feature to solve this specific problem. As I see, you need to match a substring and replace parts of it without affecting similar patterns in text which I assume should be general to be able to expand.

> if anyone knows a solution in some other dialect...

### `awk` to the rescue

You have to use a programming language or a more powerful text-processing tool. If you have an `awk` implementation within your environment you are able to achieve what you desire in a second:

```
awk '{
    sepRe = "[ab]"
    regex = "(" sepRe "[cd] )+"
    while(match($0, regex)) {
        str = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        current = str
        gsub(sepRe, "", current)
        sub(str, current, $0)
    }
    print;
}' file
```

`$ cat file`:

```
ac ad bc bc ad
ac same ab ad af
```

Running `awk` outputs:

```
c d c c ad
c same ab d af
```

Note that there is no space after last `ad`